# Take out image tag alt:missing. "image tag without an alt id is prefered and not showing missing"

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, missing-data

I want to take out the missing error that the image tag is looking for. I don't want an ult tag placeholder, trying to keep it blank on purpose until i upload the photo with browse using paper clip.

I have changed the url(:missing), to many other things like nil etc.  Is there another key word I could use.  When i run my code it gives me a missing in the spot of the image location before i browse the image. there is no problem with loading the image, just before its just in the way and doesn't look good! Thanks!!

application_helper.rb:

```rails
def form_image_select(post)  
  return image_tag post.image.url(:missing),
                   id: 'image-preview',
                   class: 'img-responsive' 

end
```

My post.js that gives me the preview!

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {  
  var output = document.getElementById('image-preview');
  output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

This is where i post it in post.html:

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
   <%= form_image_select(@post) %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want for the `alt` attribute on an image is simply the `alt` keyword on `image_tag`:

```
return image_tag post.image.url,
                   id: 'image-preview',
                   class: 'img-responsive',
                   alt: 'missing'
```

Comment: yea i can add a placeholder, however i don't want an alt image!! i have a container that will expand once my image gets selected. i dont want there to be an alt image in that place. i want it to be blank. so how could i keep it blank without "missing showing up in the area?" thank you:)

Comment: Then you could either use either `javascript:void(0)`, or create a white or transparent PNG as a placeholder and reference that.

Comment: where do you put this `javascript:void(0)`? i tried some combinations.